# When to use which type of generic interface definition?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm currently wondering when to use which type of a generic interface definition. Let's take this as an example:

```
// (I)
public interface IStorage<T>
        where T: class, new()
{
        void SaveTo(string fileName, T what);
        T LoadFrom(string fileName);
}

// (II)
public interface IStorage
{
        void SaveTo<T>(string fileName, T what)
                where T: class;
        T LoadFrom(string fileName)
                where T: class, new();
}
```

From my point of view, I would say that:

- I will use (I) if the methods within the interface (or conrete type) depend on each other and operate on the same internal data. Therefor I have IList in my mind: All methods within IList are operating on the same data. It makes sense to have one instance per conrete type.
- I will use (II) if the methods within the interface (or concrete type) are not depending on each other (so they don't operate on same internal data). That means, I could have one instance and use it for different concrete types.

So, what do you think? Is there a best practice? Other thoughts on this?

Comment: What's the actual use case? Obviously with (I) your class instance will we related to a single type, which is not the case with (II).

Comment: I think you've answered your own question in the two bullet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the difference in logical meaning of the association.

A class implementing the generic interface `Interface<Type>` will be logically associated with that Type. And all the methods of that class which refer to Type will also be associated with it.

This might lend itself well to an interface representing a Builder (pattern).

A class with generic type methods (`Type doSomething<Type>`) will have methods logically associated with the specified type when called. Different methods may expect different generic types to be provided.

This might lend itself well to an interface representing a Factory (pattern).